# How to merge array of values in Node.js by id?

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for a way to effectively merge json structure type values so that the result has values from both sides - but is merged using the id .

```
var a = [
    {
        id:"1",
        value:"one"
    },
    {
        id:"2",
        value:"two"
    },    
    {
        id:"3",
        value:"three"
    }    
]
var b = [
    {
        id:"1",
        somevalue:"foo"
    },
    {
        id:"2",
        anothervalue:"bar"
    }    
]
```

I want to end up with:

```
[
    {
        id:"1",
        value:"one",
        somevalue:"foo"
    },
    {
        id:"2",
        value:"two",
        anothervalue:"bar"
    },    
    {
        id:"3",
        value:"three"
    }
```

]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your object based on `id` and merge them using `Object.assign()` in a new object and then extract all the values using `Object.values()`.

```js
var a = [ { id:"1", value:"one" }, { id:"2", value:"two" }, { id:"3", value:"three" } ],
    b = [ { id:"1", somevalue:"foo" }, { id:"2", anothervalue:"bar" } ],
    merged = Object.values([].concat(a,b).reduce((r,o) => {
      r[o.id] = Object.assign(r[o.id] || {}, o);
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(merged);
```

Comment: This is why I like javascript! You can do so many fancy and short things with it :)

Answer (score 1):

> You can use loadash merge

If you want `a` and `b` not to be modified, use

`result = _.merge([], a, b)`.

or with `_.merge(a, b)`, you will have your result in `a`.

Comment: While this may work, its not a good solution if you have to use another external library to accomplish a goal which you could have solved using a simple loop or what @Hassan Ihman posted.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and clean solution using lodash could be :

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var mapA = _.indexBy(a, "id");
var mapB = _.indexBy(b, "id");

var mapResult = _.merge({}, mapA, mapB);
var mapValues = _.values(mapResult);

console.log(mapValues);
```

Comment: While this may work, its not a good solution if you have to use another external library to accomplish a goal which you could have solved using a simple loop or what @Hassan Ihman posted.